# Failure sending mail Exception while sending mail through SMTP

Tags: vb.net, smtp, windows

> Dim mail As New Net.Mail.MailMessage()
>
> ```
>         mail.From = New Net.Mail.MailAddress("abc@xyz.com")
>         mail.[To].Add("abc@xyz.com")
>         mail.IsBodyHtml = True
>         mail.Subject = "A subject line."
>         mail.Body = "A mail body message."
>         Dim smtp As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.xyz.com", 25)
>         smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@xyz.com","password")
>         Try
>             smtp.Send(mail)
>             MsgBox("Your Email has been sent sucessfully - Thank You")
>         Catch exc As Exception
>             MsgBox("Send failure: " & exc.ToString())
>         End Try
> ```

In Windows Application a simple SMTP using Credential, throwing Exception-

Failure sending mail.

Why it is throwing can anybody help me out.

Comment: What is in the `InnerException` property of the exception thrown? Furthermore, can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Give a look at InnerException.Message of your Exception.

Comment: InnerException: InnerException = {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}

Comment: Check if your firewall blocks port 25.

Comment: also add the line smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False before the try, Best make sure firewall and the exchange or isp allow mails from your ip. I know this may not be an issue but it was for me a while back.

Comment: Dim smtp As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.xyz.com", 25) - 25 is given here.

smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False [Still not working]